# PHP-FPM and NGINX on AltServer: 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: database, nginx, mariadb, nginx-config

After setup Bookstack, i have error "502 Bad Gateway"
OS - Alt Server 10
Code from /etc/nginx/sites-avialable.d/bookstack.conf:
Example i take from [Github](https://github.com/BookStackApp/devops/blob/main/config/nginx/ubuntu-1604-install-config)

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name 127.0.0.1;

  root /var/www/bookstack/public;
  index index.php index.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }
  
  location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
  }
}
```

Code from /var/www/bookstack/.env:

```
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1

# Database details
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=bookstack
DB_USERNAME=bookstack
DB_PASSWORD=bookstack

# Mail system to use
# Can be 'smtp' or 'sendmail'
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

# Mail sender details
MAIL_FROM_NAME="BookStack"
MAIL_FROM=bookstack@example.com

# SMTP mail options
# These settings can be checked using the "Send a Test Email"
# feature found in the "Settings > Maintenance" area of the system.
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Code from /var/log/nginx/error.log:

```
2023/04/27 02:59:57 [crit] 20019#20019: *1 connect() to unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1"
```

But in /run/php/ i don't have that file. I don't have folder php in /run too.
Bit if i delete

```
  location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
  }
```

from /etc/nginx/sites-avialable.d/bookstack.conf, i have same error, but some txt file download after refresh page.

I remake database for bookstack, remake user for her and privileges.
Check many solutions on internet, but nothing was suitable for my case.
I expect at least right direction in way, where i can will find further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to explain you the core concepts of what you are trying to do so you will be able to configure it properly the next time by yourself.

First of all I have never heard of "AltServer10" which makes it not super easy for you to follow general tutorials how to setup up an application stack using NGINX and PHP-FPM.But I did some research for you.

### PHP FPM

1st make sure you have installed your PHP-FPM. This is the package definition:
https://packages.altlinux.org/en/p10/srpms/php8.1-fpm-fcgi/

I have no idea what oackage manager AltServer is using ... So you should have a look on this one.

After the installation of FPM you have to configure the FPMs PHP worker pools.

On Ubuntu, RHEL, CentOS the configuration file will be in `/etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d` and named `www.conf`. In case you are using other packages the configuration path can be different. Remi will point to
``

I always change my setting to map the run user of NGINX like this. Please not this is not the full `www.conf`!

```bash
; Unix user/group of processes
; Note: The user is mandatory. If the group is not set, the default user's group
;       will be used.
; RPM: apache user chosen to provide access to the same directories as httpd
user = nginx
; RPM: Keep a group allowed to write in log dir.
group = nginx

; The address on which to accept FastCGI requests.
; Valid syntaxes are:
;   'ip.add.re.ss:port'    - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv4 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   '[ip:6:addr:ess]:port' - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv6 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   'port'                 - to listen on a TCP socket to all addresses
;                            (IPv6 and IPv4-mapped) on a specific port;
;   '/path/to/unix/socket' - to listen on a unix socket.
; Note: This value is mandatory.
listen = /var/run/php80-fpm.sock

; Set listen(2) backlog.
; Default Value: 511
;listen.backlog = 511

; Set permissions for unix socket, if one is used. In Linux, read/write
; permissions must be set in order to allow connections from a web server.
; Default Values: user and group are set as the running user
;                 mode is set to 0660
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0660
```

The `listen` configuration is important. It tells the FPM where to put the socket (in this case) we can send request (from NGINX) to.

This has to match your nginx configuration. But first let's create / start the FPM Serivce. Again, no idea how to that on AltServer but in case Alt is using `systemd` and `systemctl` you can do something like
`/bin/systemctl start php8-fpm.service`

I have looked into the AltServer FPM Package and it is likely the service will named like this. Look here: https://packages.altlinux.org/en/p10/srpms/php8.1-fpm-fcgi/specfiles/

Okay, now you should have a FPM service up and running. Plese check the run directory. It should have a `sock` file like `/var/run/php80-fpm.sock`

### NGINX

My NGINX PHP looks like

```
location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php80-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
```

Please check whats in your `fastcgi.conf`. It should include some of the `fcgi` directive listed above.

This will be enough to make your PHP application work. A very good tutorial can be found on DigitalOcean: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/php-fpm-nginx

It covers Ubuntu but you should be able to adapt it.

An alternative to NGINX with PHP-FPM is NGINX Unit.

Also available on AltServer: https://packages.altlinux.org/en/p10/srpms/unit/

Make sure you are installing Unit + the language Module for PHP `unit-php`.
Look here: https://packages.altlinux.org/en/p10/binary/unit-php/x86_64/

The configuration will be much easier as the only thing you have to do is creating an Unit Configuration and apply it. Described here:

http://unit.nginx.org/configuration/#php